# Inserting data using Linq to SQL with foreign keys

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, visual-studio, linq

I have a database that contains 'Personne' table, 'Patient' table (this one contains a foreign key to the id of 'Personne'), and 'RendezVous' table. i want to add a new element on my RendezVous table, but in my 'RendezVous' table i want the idPatient, and i am entering the first and last name in my app so i have to do a search on 'Personne' table to get the idPerson, and search that id on my 'Patient' table to get it the idPatient. If the patient doesn't exist, i put the id on 1. I'm using LinQ to SQL, but it doesn't work... Can i get some help?

```
public void AddRdv(DateTime date, byte idMedecin, string nomPatient, string prenomPatient, bool important, string notes)
    {
        string con = $@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename={System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)}\MCDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        MCDataClassDataContext dataClass = new MCDataClassDataContext(con);
        var patientRdv = (from personne in dataClass.Personne
                          where nomPatient == personne.nom && prenomPatient == personne.prenom
                          join patient in dataClass.Patient on personne.Id equals patient.IdPersonne
                          select personne);
        Personne pers=patientRdv.First();

        if (patientRdv.Count()!=0)
        {
            pers = patientRdv.First();
            RendezVous rdv = new RendezVous
            {
                Date = date,
                IdPatient = pers.Id,
                IdMedecin = idMedecin,
                Important = important,
                Fait = false,
                Note = notes
            };
            dataClass.RendezVous.InsertOnSubmit(rdv);
            dataClass.SubmitChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            RendezVous rdv = new RendezVous
            {
                Date = date,
                IdPatient = 1,
                IdMedecin = idMedecin,
                Important = important,
                Fait = false,
                Note = notes
            };
            dataClass.RendezVous.InsertOnSubmit(rdv);
            dataClass.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in there, what are you getting into `Personne`?

Comment: That's the problem, when i make pers=patientRdv.First(); i got that the sequency is empty

Comment: If you do the query in SSMS, do you get data?

Comment: Im new to c#/database programming, what is ssms?

Comment: SSMS means sql server management studio. If you run similar query in Sql (using SSMS) does it return records.

Comment: This line must contain the Generic, like so -                                    Personne pers=patientRdv.First<Personne>();